# Filling a container with text area

Tags: android

My main activity window is looking really ugly. Since i tried and worked over a tutorial now my final part is to set the size to be full of the screen (portrait/landscape)

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="521dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hscrll1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/table_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:stretchColumns="0">
                </TableLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Adding rows in this table layout is going dynamically and the code is shown bellow :

```
// border
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Changes this drawbale to use a single 
color instead of a gradient
gd.setCornerRadius(5);
gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);

// draw table header
final TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);
TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
tbrow0.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

tv0.setText(" Type ");
tv0.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv0.setBackground(gd);
tv0.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
tv0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow0.addView(tv0);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText(" Year ");
tv1.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv1.setBackground(gd);
tbrow0.addView(tv1);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
tv2.setText(" Month ");
tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv2.setBackground(gd);
tbrow0.addView(tv2);

TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
tv3.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
tv3.setText(" Week ");
tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv3.setBackground(gd);
tbrow0.addView(tv3);

TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
tv4.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
tv4.setText(" Amount ");
tv4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
tv4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv4.setBackground(gd);
tbrow0.addView(tv4);

stk.addView(tbrow0);
```

Even its so much code the control still looks like wrong placed like shown on picture bellow :

[image]

Can anyone take a look on my main activity and tell me what am i doing wrong here.

The final output should be the table well placed from edge to edge with same row width and height size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by changing activity to this solved the issue

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="613dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*"></TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```